# How did the Creed start?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I want to know why and how the Creed started. I am new to the series. I have beat *Assassin's Creed II* and *Assassin's Creed III*. I am about to beat the original *Assassin's Creed* and *Assassin's Creed IV: Black Flag*.

Comment: Short story, to stop the Templars

Comment: Also before you play 4, play Brother hood and Revaltaions. they're important to the series

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say whether you're avoiding spoilers or not, and the answer to this is full of more spoilers than you might think. Think carefully whether you actually want to know about the origin of the Order of Assassins before you continue!

You can learn a lot from the [Assassin's Creed wiki](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Assassins). Specifically, the origin of the creed:

> The bloodline of the original Assassins was formed centuries ago, after various members of the First Civilization conceived children with members of the human race. These children had the visual appearance of humans, but were gifted with several extra senses from the precursor race, such as what the former dubbed "Eagle Vision".